# "Missing requirements" when defining an Eclipse target platform with RAP and Teneo

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-rap, target-platform, teneo

I created a target file and added the RAP target platform and a local folder with some proprietary bundles. When I tried to add the other dependencies for Teneo and Hibernate as stated in [this tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Teneo/Hibernate/Download_and_Install#Plugins_and_dependencies.2C_update_site_locations), some dependencies for Teneo are not satisfied.

This is my target definition file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="server.platform" sequenceNumber="222">
<locations>
  <location path="<My_bundles_dir>" type="Directory"/>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.rap.examples.feature.feature.group" version="2.3.0.20140602-1108"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rap.feature.feature.group" version="2.3.0.20140610-0925"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rap.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="2.3.0.20140610-0925"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rap.equinox.target.feature.feature.group" version="2.3.0.20140608-1653"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/2.3/R-20140610-0925/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.hibernate.feature.group" version="4.1.1.201310261216"/>
<unit id="org.hsqldb.feature.group" version="2.2.8.201310261216"/>
<unit id="com.db4o.feature.group" version="7.4.155.v20120928-1733"/>
<unit id="org.apache.log4j.feature.group" version="1.2.16.201310261216"/>
<unit id="org.dom4j.feature.group" version="1.6.1.201310261216"/>
<unit id="org.apache.commons.logging.feature.group" version="1.1.1.201310261216"/>
<unit id="org.postgresql.feature.group" version="9.0.0.201310261216"/>
<unit id="com.mysql.jdbc.feature.group" version="5.1.11.201310261216"/>
<unit id="javax.persistence.feature.group" version="2.0.1.201310261216"/>
<unit id="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.feature.group" version="3.0.1301.201310261216"/>
<repository location="http://www.elver.org/eclipse/2.0.0/update"/>
</location>
</locations>
</target>
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Missing requirement: EMF Common UI 2.9.0.v20140519-0339 (org.eclipse.emf.common.ui.feature.group 2.9.0.v20140519-0339) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to satisfy all dependencies one by one (...well what else i can do?) and i end up with the following error:

Missing requirement: EMF Common UI 2.9.0.v20140519-0339 (org.eclipse.emf.common.ui.feature.group 2.9.0.v20140519-0339) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: What is your target definition? You should define it in a `xxx.target` file so that you can post it here. The information you currently provide is not sufficient to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> ... requires 'org.eclipse.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found

The problem with your target definition is that you don't specify any p2 repository that contains this dependency. So you e.g. need to add Luna release train repository: `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna`

The PDE editor is not particularly helpful when it comes to adding p2 repositories which are only needed for dependencies. But you can resort to using a text editor to modify the target file. Here is what you need to do to add a p2 repository for adding dependencies:

1. Copy one of the `location` lines with `type="InstallableUnit"` and paste it below the last closing location tag (`</location>`).
2. Add the repository, e.g. with

   ```
   <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna"/>
   ```
3. Add a closing repository tag.
4. Increment the `sequenceNumber` attribute in the root element.
5. Save the file and open it with the Target Definition Editor again. Dependencies to artifacts in the newly added repository can now be resolved.